# Update server-processed DataTables source with additional parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox, datatables

I'm trying to pass additional parameters (list of selected checkboxes) to a server-processed DataTables-table **#my_table** when a *Submit* input button has been clicked:

[image: screenshot]

Which probably means I must set the **my_table.sAjaxSource** to the backend script *plus* a compiled list of checkboxes and then call **my_table.fnDraw()**?

I've prepared a very simple test case - **test.php**:

```
<?php
error_log('QUERY_STRING: ' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
?>
```

and **index.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
        @import "/css/demo_table_jui.css";
        @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css";
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>;
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>;
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        my_table = $('#my_table').dataTable( {
                bJQueryUI: true,
                bServerSide: true,
                bProcessing: true,
                sAjaxSource: '/test.php'
        } );
});

var my_table;

function redrawTable() {
        var str = '';
        var boxes = new Array();

        //loop through all checkboxes
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                boxes.push($(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).val());
            }
        });

        str = '/test.php?' + boxes.join('&');
        // TODO: set my_table.sAjaxSource to str
        my_table.fnDraw();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Select fruit:</p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="apple">apple</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="banana">banana</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="pear">pear</label></p>

<p>Select candy:</p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="candy" value="toffee">toffee</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="candy" value="fudge">fudge</label></p>

<p><input type="button" onclick="redrawTable();" value="Submit"></p>

<table class="display" id="my_table">

<thead>
<tr>
<th>Column_1</th>
<th>Column_2</th>
<th>Column_3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Please advise me, how to achieve this (passing custom params to DataTables AJAX source script).

**UPDATE:** this code seems to work well for me, thanks Nicola

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
        @import "/css/demo_table_jui.css";
        @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css";
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var my_table;

$(function() { 
        my_table = $('#my_table').dataTable( {
                bJQueryUI: true,
                bServerSide: true,
                bProcessing: true,
                sAjaxSource: '/test.php',
                fnServerParams: function ( aoData ) {
                        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
                            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                                aoData.push( { name: $(this).attr('name'), value: $(this).val() } );
                            }
                        });
                } 
        });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Select fruit:</p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="apple">apple</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="banana">banana</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="pear">pear</label></p>

<p>Select candy:</p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="candy" value="toffee">toffee</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="candy" value="fudge">fudge</label></p>

<p><input type="button" onclick="my_table.fnDraw();" value="Submit"></p>

<table class="display" id="my_table">

<thead>
<tr>
<th>Column_1</th>
<th>Column_2</th>
<th>Column_3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

And in the error_log I see:

```
QUERY_STRING: 
sEcho=2&
iColumns=3&
sColumns=&
iDisplayStart=0&
iDisplayLength=10&
mDataProp_0=0&
mDataProp_1=1&
mDataProp_2=2&
sSearch=&
bRegex=false&
sSearch_0=&
bRegex_0=false&
bSearchable_0=true&
sSearch_1=&
bRegex_1=false&
bSearchable_1=true&
sSearch_2=&
bRegex_2=false&
bSearchable_2=true&
iSortingCols=1&
iSortCol_0=0&
sSortDir_0=asc&
bSortable_0=true&
bSortable_1=true&
bSortable_2=true&
fruits=apple&
fruits=banana&
candy=toffee&
candy=fudge&
_=1317666289823
```

Comment: I super-appreciate you posting your working code *and* giving props to Nicola who gave you the key.  (instead of posting your solution as an answer and giving yourself credit)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see from [this](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html) example you should use fnServerParams:

```
"fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
  aoData.push( { "name": "more_data", "value": "my_value" } );
}
```

where aoData is an array of objects to send to the server

Comment: Thanks! Do I still need to call fnDraw()?